# Ruby On Rails Querying From a model but returning another tables fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
active_courses_past_week = CourseEnrollment.select("courses.*").
joins(:course).
where("date(course_enrollments.created_at) BETWEEN ? and ?", Date.parse(start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), Date.parse(end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))).
group("courses.id")
```

The above query seems odd because I am querying from course enrollments, but only care about the course data where they are enrolled between two dates. It just seems weird because I am not using any of the fields in the CourseErnollment model. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would write it using a range instead of "raw" SQL.

```
active_courses_past_week = CourseEnrollment.where(:created_at =>  start_date..end_date))
                                           .joins(:course)
                                           .group(courses.id)
```